# HTML/JS Show a text next to a input box

Tags: javascript

I want to put a text next to an input box, after an successful if clause.
Just need to know how to show up such text.

Thanks

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" name="username" required autofocus/>`
And my code snippet:
`$("#username").append("<p>This username is not available</p>");`

Comment: Can you please provide a little more context? Where is the text coming from? Is it the same string every time? On a broad level, you could just use jquery for the task of placing text next to a div.

Comment: Just a random text I can specify, and just for 1 time. As I said just need to know the theory.

Comment: The 'theory' is somewhat different depending on the specific context, though, which is why Wold asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using jQuery, you can simply use:

`$("#your-element-id").append("<strong>whatever text you need to add</strong>");`

You will need to make sure that `#your-element-id` contains the input box. You may need to add the relavant CSS as well.

Comment: Without your code snippet, nobody can tell what will show up.

Comment: #username is not the parent container. You need to add text beside the input box and for that you need to manipulate the parent containing the input box. Do it like this:
$("#element-id-that-contains-username").append("<strong>whatever text you need to add</strong>");

Comment: Thanks, I put the input in a single div and now it works, haven't thinked about this.

Comment: Your welcome, but next time post a more clear question with what you've tried or some code so that people don't get annoyed ;)